# Apache won't start - PHP issues?

Tags: server, apache2, php, webmin, virtualmin

I'm somewhat of a Ubuntu newb and have recently set-up a ubuntu VPS (on the azure network). I am using webmin / virtualmin as a means to administer the server and quickly * easily create and administer virtual hosting accounts.

After doing some package updayes via the webmin interface, the system rebooted. On relaunching webmin i could see that the apache server wasn't running. When I tried to restart it, webmin displayed the following error:

> Failed to start service :
>
> - Starting web server apache2
>
>   - - The apache2 configtest failed.
>         Output of config test was:
>         AH00526: Syntax error on line 40 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/apn.codeclinic.de.conf:
>         Invalid command 'php_admin_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
>         Action 'configtest' failed.
>         The Apache error log may have more information.

If I comment out this line it just fails at the next php reference, and if I comment this one out it simply fails on the config file for the next virtual server(website).

So looking at the command shell I ran

> sudo apt-get -f install

Which gives me the following areas of interest(it prints out a huge list of things but these are the most notable errors to me):

> dpkg: error processing package php5-cgi (--configure):
>
> subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>
> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php5:
>
> php5 depends on libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.7) | libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.7) | php5-cgi (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.7) | php5-fpm (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.7); however:
>
> Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not configured yet.
>
> Package libapache2-mod-php5filter is not installed.
>
> Package php5-cgi is not configured yet.
>
> Package php5-fpm is not installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package php5 (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>
> No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
>
> No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
>
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> php5-cli
>
> php5-readline
>
> libapache2-mod-php5
>
> linux-cloud-tools-common
>
> php-pear
>
> php5-cgi
>
> php5
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I also tried

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5 -y

But get the following output:

> Reading package lists...
>   Building dependency tree...
>   Reading state information...
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
>   7 not fully installed or removed.
>   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>   E: Internal Error, No file name for php5:amd64

I'm now really stuck as all my clients websites are down, and stupidly it seems my backup schedule was never setup properly.

So I know I'm stupid, but please help. ;-)

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: @jos doesn-t work. just returns the same

Comment: You will need to solve the dependencies first or otherwise you will never be able to use apt-get again. At this point it may be wise to completely uninstall php5 and rerun my command, then try to install php5.

Comment: Just to limit my chances of messing it up even further, how do i 'completely uninstall php5' ?

Comment: So, i did 'sudo apt-get purge php5 -y' followed by 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' and that gives the same output essentially.

Comment: I did notice that further up I see 'dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-cloud-tools-common (3.13.0-46.79) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript hv-kvp-daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package linux-cloud-tools-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1' which is something I had trouble with previously.

Comment: From googling a bit I gather there are many, many problems with the installation of libapache2-mod-php5. Assuming your Apache installation has finished OK, could you try `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`? If anything, the output will probably give some more info.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn-t help either. Im fairly convinced the problem lies with linux-cloud-tools-common since this has been floating around unconfigured for a while. I though it had somehow been resolved but evidently not. Ive never been able to get it to configure.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a LAMP server, I go in the following order; 1. Apache, 2. PHP, 3. MySQL

So for you I would run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5
```

It won't remove the current configurations for either Apache or PHP but should at least be a bit more specific to troubleshoot then `dpkg --configure -a` as depending on which fails first Apache or PHP, you can then focus on where the problem lies.